# How to generate an 8 digit string from a given short string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to generate an 8-digit string from a given short string, with a condition. The condition is that if the given string is less then 8 digits long then add 9 for the missing entries.

Let's say, 
the input is 123 the output should be 12399999
if 0123  then 012399999
if 01203 then 01203999
if 1230 then 12309999 and so on...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0123 isn't a number - so in reality, you're dealing with a string of digits, which makes it simple ... `"0123".padEnd(8, '9')`

Comment: So basically you want to padRight with '9's ?

Comment: @George - it's called padEnd now :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `padEnd` is a better term than `padRight` when you consider RTL languages like Hebrew and Arabic.

Comment: `number` values in JavaScript cannot have leading zeroes. An integer literal with a leading zero is actually an Octal number, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Dai - that's why padRight/padLeft no longer exist in modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, so you can see how the value types change (as you're performing String operations on a Number type!)

```
const someNumber: number = 123;
const asText    : string = someNumber.toString();
const padded    : string = asText.padEnd( 8, '9' );
const asNumber  : number = parseInt( padded, 10 ); // ALWAYS specify the radix!
```

As a function:

```
function padNinesNumber( value: number ): number {

    const asText    : string = value.toString();
    const padded    : string = asText.padEnd( 8, '9' );
    const asNumber  : number = parseInt( padded, 10 ); // ALWAYS specify the radix!
}
```

Comment: the problem with this answer is that `0123` and `01203` wont produce the expected result - the OP is dealing with strings of digits, not numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean,
Try this, I gave the code to add '9' for every difference of 8 with the number of char in the string.:

```js
const addNine = val => 
  val.toString()+'9'.repeat(8-val.toString().length);

console.log(addNine('2233'))
console.log(addNine('012303'))
console.log(addNine(1230))
```

or you can try this if you're not giving number data type

```js
console.log(('2233').padEnd(8,'9'))
console.log(('012303').padEnd(8,'9'))
```